# Kotlin kapt and android architecture components build fail

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'am using Kotlin, kapt and Android Architecture components. When I build project everything seems fine but after trying to run app on device/emulator Gradle's :assemble task  throw these errors:

> Warning:warning: Supported source version 'RELEASE_7' from annotation processor 'android.arch.persistence.room.RoomProcessor' less than -source '1.8'
>
> Warning:warning: Supported source version 'RELEASE_7' from annotation processor 'android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleProcessor' less than -source '1.8'
>
> Warning:warning: The following options were not recognized by any processor: '[kapt.kotlin.generated]'

And build fails. Can someone help me with it?

**UPDATE**

- module build.gradle [HERE](https://gist.github.com/antonkazakov/6a86baa2d829ff6590b1a38fe8b4dbec)
- project build.gradle [HERE](https://gist.github.com/antonkazakov/5c05e60080969786e23a76acdbfe144e)

Comment: Could you post your build gradle here? And just to be clear, you've added the plugin, dependencies and any addition folder if necessary for kotlin to run? Not doing so may result in a build because certain things aren't packaged.

Comment: @AllanW hey check out build.gradle files i've added :)

Comment: The only difference my gradle has from yours is that I don't have `apply plugin: kotlin-kapt`. I still have kapt dependencies and they seem to be working fine. I also have `kapt {
    generateStubs = true
}` in my app gradle (at the very end outside any other tags) though I'm not sure if that is your issue. Have a go at those two things

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem with version 1.0.0-alpha3, but with version 1.0.0-alpha1 everything works fine.

Comment: well anyway i don't think downgrading to 1.0 alpha to solve my issue is good idea :)

Comment: i am using 1.1.2-5 which is not alpha

Comment: version of android.arch.lifecycle.Lifecycle, not Kotlin

Comment: oh sry. i will try

Comment: Last version of Kotlin and google arch stuff solved problem. so i will approve this answer. If anyone still have the same issue just be sure that you are using last versions.